# Spatial clustering with areas in QGIS or Python

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, clustering

I am working in QGIS with shapefiles containing several polygon features with various areas.

I would like to cluster neighbor polygons in a way that results in clusters of approximately the same total areas, and aim for a given target area.

In other words, I would like to perform spatial clustering, but also take into account the polygons areas.

I can try to implement a solution in python to solve this issue.

But before I do, I would like to ask if such a solution already exists, ideally in QGIS, or as python script?

I have already looked for such clustering, but I have mostly found solutions with clusters of the *same number of polygons* ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303524/clustering-spatially-connected-polygons-so-all-clusters-have-approximately-the-s) or [here](https://spatialthoughts.com/2021/01/31/equal-sized-kmeans-qgis/)), instead of the *same total area* (example of similar questions without answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226042/spatial-clustering-with-attribute) or [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213170/spatial-clustering-with-roughly-equal-sizes)).

Here is a screenshot of some of the polygons I am working with.

[image: polygons_example]